# Futuro do java no chrome - possíveis complicações

Tags: java, google-chrome

De acordo com essa noticia do **[Techtudo](http://www.techtudo.com.br/dicas-e-tutoriais/noticia/2015/04/chrome-42-chega-com-45-correcoese-problemas-com-java-saiba-resolver.html)** o chrome deixará de suportar o protocolo NPAPI usado pelo java para fazer a comunicação entre o java e o chrome

Tenho muitos programas web que necessitam do java rodando, gostaria de saber se é possível mesmo depois que o chrome desabilitar o NPAPI, ainda assim fazer as aplicações java funcionarem?

### Trecho da noticia

> Para o usuário final, a principal mudança a ser notada é a falta de
>   compatibilidade com o Java e outros plugins usados por sites de
>   bancos. Isso acontece porque, progressivamente, o navegador deixará
>   de suportar o protocolo NPAPI, que é usado por esses plugins para
>   comunicação com o Google Chrome.
>          O suporte ao protocolo será totalmente encerrado em setembro, mas até    lá ainda é possível para ativar o recurso e continuar
>   usando os    plugins que dependem do NPAPI. Confira como ativar
>   abaixo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Troque de navegador

A [recomendação da Oracle](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml) é considerar alternativas como Firefox, Internet Explorer e Safari.

> [...] we strongly recommend Java users consider alternatives to Chrome as soon as possible. Instead, we recommend Firefox, Internet Explorer and Safari as longer-term options.

## Motivação

O Google [anunciou](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/11/the-final-countdown-for-npapi.html) a depreciação da NPAPI há algum tempo e afirmou que o objetivo, além de evitar vários problemas de segurança, é de tornar a web mais amigável aos dispositivos móveis.

Ainda não há uma posição oficial da Oracle ou Google sobre alternativas para executar o Java talvez com outro API.

## [Cronograma](http://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation)

- **Janeiro de 2014**: Chrome versão 32 adiciona uma barra de confirmação para execução de plugins que usam a tecnologia NPAPI.
- **Meio de 2014**: maior dificuldade para permitir a execução dos plugins, de forma a desencorajar seu uso.
- **Janeiro de 2015**: plugins com NPAPI são bloqueados por padrão, sendo necessário ao usuário habilitá-los manualmente.
- **Abril de 2015**: no Chrome versão 42 os plugins que usam NPAPI serão desabilitados por padrão e serão removidas da Chrome Web Store. Somente alguns plugins mais usados permitirão a execução por padrão através de uma *whitelist* ("lista branca"), estando o plugin do Java nesta lista. O processo para ativar um plugin desse tipo é ainda mais complicado.
- **Setembro de 2015**: no Chrome versão 45 a NPAPI será completamente removida do navegador.

Answer (score 2):

Com a versão atual (42) ainda se pode utilizar através da instalação de um plugin baseado na NPAPI. Neste link demonstra como é feita a ativação.[Ativando a NPAPI no Chrome Versão 42 e mais recentes](https://www.java.com/pt_BR/download/faq/chrome.xml#npapichrome)