# Problema com relatorio JasperReports e Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, jasper-reports

Apos a ultima atualização do Google Chrome alguns relatórios da minha aplicação Web simplesmente não aparecem. Ativei o NPAPI no Chrome mas mesmo assim não funcionou o relatório. Alguém está tendo esse mesmo problema?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59266/